# How to load jquery accordion into a div using ajax load?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a jquery accordion that works fine on its own. When I try to load it into a div located on my home page using a link and the load method, the accordion appears as a list with headings and loses all its functionality.
My working accordion can be found in http://jsfiddle.net/jenova007/jhhpovzb/
I would like to load this accordion into the "result" div when I click on the "Store Locations" link.  After making many attempts I end up loading the original accordion page or loading a list of accordion headings and list items but not the working accordion in the div.
After reading a couple of articles on reinitialising the accordion on load etc, I am still lost.  Could someone please explain how I can go about doing that in my javascript?  Thank you.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$('a').click(function() {
var page = $(this).attr('href');
$('#result').load(page);
return false;
});
</script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Store_Locations</title>
<style type="text/css">
#result {position: absolute;
 top: 30%;
 left: 0;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="StoreListA.html">Store Locations</a>
<div id="result">
</div>
<script src="loader.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize your accordion after loading. You should wait for loading callback.

```
$("#result").load(page + " #result", function() {

    // This is a callback function. Do initialization here.

});
```

Comment: Yes, the accordion works fine.  But I would like this accordion to be loaded in the result div in the StoreLocations.html page which contains the "Store Locations" link (which the user should click in order to display the accordion).  Instead when I click on the link, it refreshes the entire StoreLocations.html page and loads the accordion,StoreListA.html page.  In other words, I only want to refresh the result div in the StoreLocations.html page.
How do I go about it?  Thank you.

Comment: So the problem is you don't want to load the whole StoreListA.html page into your `#result` div but only to refresh this div's content, right?

Comment: Yes. When I click on the link in StoreLocations.html, I want to load the accordion contained in StoreListA.html into the #result div contained in StoreLocations.html.  I want to keep the StoreLocations.html and all its items as they are but only refresh the #result div and display this div as formatted in StoreLocations.html. Although I am not sure where I should actually format the accordion - in StoreLocations.html or in StoreListA.html.  Thank you.

Comment: @Kira, you can define what portion of loaded page you want to include to your `#result` div. See http://api.jquery.com/load/#script-execution

Comment: @Kira, I've updated the answer. I assumed that you have the same `#result` div in your StoreListA.html page.